# Python dictionary switching keys around in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have a dictionary in python in which I have a number for the key with a value attatched to it.

```
myDictionary = {"0" :0, "1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0, "5":0, "6":12, "7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0, "12":0,"13":12}
```

I run a doctest that says:

```
>>> myDictionary = {"0" :0, "1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0, "5":0, "6":12, "7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0, "12":0,"13":12}
>>> new_Val = 0
>>> method0 = WordClass (new_Val, myDictionary)
True
```

I was doing some debugging ad printed out my dictionary to make sure I was going through the right values in the dictionary. When I printed it out, it looked like this:

```
{'11': 4, '10': 4, '13': 0, '12': 4, '1': 4, '0': 4, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 4, '4': 4, '7': 4, '6': 0, '9': 4, '8': 4}
```

They are all out of order. Does python do that by default when storing memory or something? If so, is there some documentation somewhere that I can look at?

Thank you

Comment: [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are unordered by definition. Why not use a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionaries in python are unordered.  Do you actually need an order?  If you elaborate on this a bit people may be able to help you more.  You can try using something like https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict if you really need it to be ordered.

Comment: Well, they have to be ordered to iterate through them right? I want to be able to get the value at each one going through a for loop

Comment: @LearnLanguages96, you can't iterate through a ```dict``` directly.  What you can do is generate a list of keys, and then loop through that and sequentially call up the values.  This is what implicitly happens when you do ```for thing in a_dict:```, each ```thing``` will be a key of the dictionary ```a_dict``` (which pops up in an arbitrary order)

Comment: Why do they need to be ordered?  You could do `for key in dict` or `for item in dict.items()` with no expectation of getting them back in any particular order, or even the same order twice.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionary keys are unordered.  If you want them back in a particular order, you need to sort them.  If you want a dictionary to remember the order in which keys were added, use `OrderedDict()` from `collections`.

More info: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict